# how do i create an automated sql restore script for multiple backups?

Tags: sql, automation, restore

Hello to all SQL gurus out there. 
I basically have 6 daily sql backups (.bak) that need a restore everyday. I want to automate this process by having the sql agent run the script daily. I have the following restore script written, and I know it's not completely correct, that is why I'm here to ask for any pointers is much appreciated! I'm also still new to writing SQL stored procedures, but my job entails a lot of it. So, I'm learning all this as I go. I welcome any help. :) Thanks a bunch everyone!

```
use master;
go

set nocount on

-- 1 - variable declaration 
declare @dbname nvarchar(max) --database to restore 
declare @backuppath nvarchar(max) --backup location
declare @filelisttable --list the table to populate 
declare @sql nvarchar(max) --dynamic sql 
declare @mdf nvarchar(max) --logical primary data file
declare @ndf nvarchar(max) --logical 2nd data file
declare @ldf nvarchar(max) --logical log data file
declare @dp nvarchar(200) --data file path
declare @lp nvarchar(200) --log file path
declare @backupfile nvarchar(500)

-- 2 - initialize variables
set @dbname = 'test'
set @backuppath = '\\mybackuppath\c$\test'

-- 3 - get list of files
insert into @filelisttable exec('restore filelistonly from disk = ''' +@backuppath+'''') --temptable to retrieve all back up files 

-- 4 - retrieve top 6 recent data extracts 
select  @backuppath  = max(backupfile)
from @filelist
where backupfile like '%.bak' --how to pick up most recent 6 back up files w/timestamp on trails?

set @sql = ('use [master])
    restore database @dbname ['+@dbname+']
        from disk = N'''+@backuppath+'''
            with replace,
            move N'''+@mdf+''' to N'''+@mdf+'''
            move N'''+@ndf+''' to N'''+@ndf+'''
            move N'''+@ldf+''' to N'''+@ldf+''''

-- 5- the 6 backup files that need to be restored daily

/** I have to run this manually everyday, and I want to automate this.
RESTORE DATABASE test FROM
    DISK = 'C:\test\test_Customer_20160518_1.bak',
    DISK = 'C:\test\test_Customer_20160518_2.bak',
    DISK = 'C:\test\test_Customer_20160518_3.bak',
    DISK = 'C:\test\test_Customer_20160518_4.bak',
    DISK = 'C:\test\test_Customer_20160518_5.bak',
    DISK = 'C:\test\test_Customer_20160518_6.bak'
    WITH REPLACE,
    MOVE 'test_Data1' TO 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_CUSTOMER.mdf',
    MOVE 'test_Data2' TO 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_CUSTOMER_1.ndf',
    MOVE 'test_Log' TO 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_CUSTOMER_2.ldf'
    GO
**/

use master 
alter database test set multi_user with rollback immediate;

go

return
```

Comment: You'll want to familiarize yourself with the backupset table located in msdb. You should also probably post this on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh, thank you supergrady! :) Will do now.

Comment: From the sample I see that you need to change the date value. Save prepared text with `DISK = 'C:\test\test_Customer_|replaceMe|_4.bak',` and run daily with automatic replacement. This is not huge work if you speak about 6 (not 6,000) databases.

Comment: Oh...what about setting up from single to multi user mode before and after restore? I know it should be easy from SQL guru standpoint, but not me. I can generate a manual run script, but automating the thing is tricky for me. :)